# JSON Response not reporting properly

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm using the newtonsoft.dll to deal qwith the proper JSON responses from a site, i have come in to an issue, the delete code:

```
    Dim delPro As String
    Dim resPro As String
    Dim sB As New StringBuilder()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridProjects.Rows
        If (row.Cells(4).Value IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' JSON
            delPro = srFunctions.postURL("http://www.ste.com/ajax_task.php?act=add&task=projectDelete", "project_ids=" + row.Cells(0).Value.ToString(), varCookieJar)
            resPro = srFunctions.postURL("http://www.ste.com/ajax_task.php?act=status&task=projectDelete", "", varCookieJar)

            ' purely for debugging
            sB.Append("1: " + delPro)
            sB.Append(Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine)
            sB.Append("2: " + resPro)
            sB.Append(Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine)

            ' responses
            Dim tempPost = New With {Key .message = "", Key .error = 0, Key .done = False, Key .jsdata = ""}
            Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(resPro, tempPost)
            Dim com As String = obj.message
            Dim obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of saperJsonObject)(resPro)

            If CBool((CStr(obj2.done))) Then
                dataGridProjects.Rows.Remove(row)
                Me.returnMessage("Project has been deleted!")
            Else
                dataGridProjects.Rows.Remove(row)
                Me.returnMessage("Site returned an unknown response! (The action still most likely was executed)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Returned response was: " & (CStr(obj2.done)))
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The site returns 2 different success responses, this one:

{"error":0,"done":0,"message":"\u0412\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u044f\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435: 0/1","data":[true,true,0,1]}

Has **true,true,0,1** at the end which is a success (the action is still completed) the other one looks like:

{"error":0,"done":1}

or similar, the done:1 also denotes a success, i'm not sure how to look for both success values, i know i need to edit here : If CBool((CStr(obj2.done))) Then but i'm not sure how to go about it.

any help would be great guys!

cheers

Graham

Comment: for the long form, which element of **`true,true,0,1`** indicate it is done or success?  since they do not have property names, how do you know which one to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a class structure, `DeserializeObject` is problematic (`resPro` at least is defined as `String`).  It works, and you can get the `done` property, but requires `Option Strict Off`, which is not usually a good idea.

You can also just parse the response if that status is all you need to know.

```
Public Class Russianobject
    <JsonProperty("error")>
    Public Property JError As Integer
    Public Property done As Boolean
    Public Property message As String
    Public Property data As Object()      ' object array
End Class
```

This is what the longer message looks like (you didnt post what your `saperJsonObject` looked like) .  I had to change the `Error` property because it is a reserved word in VB.  Also, I changed `done` from `Int32` to `Boolean`.  The last item, data is just an array of objects, and it is not clear which element you need.

Even though the short response does not have all these elements, you can use the same class, `message` will be empty and `data`will be `Nothing`, so you will have to check!

```
Dim jstr = from whereever russian objects come from

Dim jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Russianobject)(jstr)

If jobj.data IsNot Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("0: {0}, 1: {1}, 2:{2}, 3: {2}", jobj.data(0),
                  jobj.data(1), jobj.data(2), jobj.data(3))
Else
    Console.WriteLine(jobj.done)
End If
```

This should work whether you get a long or short response.  To simply parse it, you do not need a class:

```
' using the short one:
jstr =...from whereever   

jp = JObject.Parse(jstr)
Dim jd = jp.SelectToken("data")
If jd IsNot Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("0: {0}, 1: {1}, 2:{2}, 3: {2}", jd(0), jd(1), jd(2), jd(3))
Else
    Console.WriteLine("done = " & Convert.ToBoolean(jp("done")))
End If
```

Note that in this case, the property name is used like a key.

Output:

> 0: True, 1: True, 2:0, 3: 0
>   done = 1

The long response results in the first, the short results in the second.  Whether you use a class and deserialize to an object or simply parse it, you will have to check the `data` element for `Nothing` (as shown) since it wont exist in the short response.

Comment: Glad to help...I had to revise it because it wasnt clear which part of the `data` block acts as the `done` signal, so I showed how to read the all.